# Display Custom Error Message in required field in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

How to display custom error message, when i do not fill the required input fields it will show custom error message.I don't want this standard message(Error: You must enter a value). please give me some ideas

Answer (score 0):

try to use addError method.

Refer to this : 
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm

Comment: Hi, Tejas Kapasi give me one example

Comment: Hi, 
Simple Example would be like this,
`code
Contact cont = (Contact) stdctrl.getRecord();

if( (String.IsBlank(cont.Email) && (String.IsBlank(cont.phone) ){
cont.email.addError('Please Enter an email Address or Phone Number');
cont.phone.addError('Please Enter a Phone number or Email Address');
}else{
// do something

}
`

Comment: `for (Contact cand : contacts)
{
 if ( (null==cand.Email || cand.Email.length()==0) &&
      (null==cand.Phone || cand.Phone.length()==0) )
 {
  
  cand.email.addError('Either email or phone must be defined');
  cand.phone.addError('Either email or phone must be defined');
 }
`